# Are there any way to replace Windows API Timer (SetTimer) with native C++ code?

Tags: c++, c++11, timer

I only know there is a deadline_timer in boost. If there isn't a more native C++ code, I'll have to use the boost one.

```
// Construct a timer without setting an expiry time.
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_context);

// Set an expiry time relative to now.
timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));

// Wait for the timer to expire.
timer.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a C++ solution, but the type of logic you showed can be accomplished in Win32 using a [waitable timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/waitable-timer-objects). Create a timer object using `CreateWaitableTimer()`, make it a one-time manual-reset timer using `SetWaitableTimer()`, and then wait on it using `WaitForSingleObject()`. You could easily write a C++ class to wrap these operations.